# Fluid does not reach the bottom of the domain - why not?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am attempting to create a fluid simulation and I have created a cube for the domain (currently selected):

[image]

The other cube has its type set to "fluid" and the angled rectangle is set to "obstacle".

I clicked the "Bake" button to bake the simulation and everything seems to go well for the first few frames. However, the fluid never reaches the bottom of the domain - rather it "hovers" just above it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82919/how-can-i-fix-this-gap-in-my-fluid-domain